# Can't run python on windows anymore

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10, updates

Since the most recent update to Windows 10, I have been seeing this message every time I try to do anything with Python

[image: This app can't run on your PC]

I have reinstalled it, tried running it as administrator.  Nothing works.

Comment: Are you using the [latest version of Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)? You might want to check if an updated installer is available with compatibility fixes. You may also want to check out Python 3 if able and see if you can run that, although any code you have might have to be updated for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First make sure that `python.exe` exists in the given directory and that its not a zero-length file.  More likely though is that you installed the wrong version of python.  Make sure you download and install the x86 version as it will work on both 64-bit and x86 systems.  Do a full uninstall and install python via the [Windows x86 MSI installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/python-2.7.13.msi).

Edit:

If this doesn't work please provide more information on which specific Windows 10 version you are running and which python installer you are using.

Edit 2:

You can also get more information from the `Windows Event Log`
[image]

Comment: Hm.  It worked.  I have a 64 bit machine, so I was running the 64 bit installer, but the installer you gave me has it working.  thanks!

Comment: The 64 bit installer is intended "for AMD64/EM64T/x64, not Itanium processors".  Is it possible you have an Itanium processor?

Comment: System info tells me it is an Intel Core 64 bit x64 based processor

Comment: Happened same with me in anaconda. I tried to install Python in new conda environment and it installed latest version of python with 0 byte python.exe. Then I indicated to install older verion of python with `conda install python=3.9` and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I think the reason is that *python.exe* has size 0 Kb. It could happen because you (and me too) didn't exit from Python correctly.
The way to fix the issue is to re-install Python or download "portable" version:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-385/
By the way, one of the way to  exit from python (v3) in Windows:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have to reinstall Python.

`python.exe` inside my `env\Scripts\` became 0kb for some reason. So I created another virtual-env and copied `python.exe` from there to this folder. Then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had "This app can't run on your PC" windows 10 dialog box starting to appear after I tried to start x64 app from python script under x86 python.

Uninstalled x86 python, installed x64 python and all started to work normal.